# Month view lost in Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I've lost the little monthly calendars at the top of my Outlook Navigation Pane. Does anyone know how to get them back again?

What was this:

[image]

Has now become:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that View > To-Do Bar > Date Navigator is enabled in the menu.

Comment: Weird. It is enabled, so I see the month calenar in the To Do bar. If I turn if off, it then appears in the Navigation Pane, but is removed from the To Do bar. Is there any way to have it in both as the To Do bar appears all the time, but the Navigation Pane calendars only appear in the calendar view. And I prefer the Navigation Pane one as I can get 4 months rather than just 1.

Comment: Don't know how to show both at the same time, but you can change the number of rows of months for To DO bar in Tools -> Options -> Other -> To-Do bar, at the top change number of rows to 4 and it will show 4 rows of months like in calendar bar. Another thing - if you hide (minimize) the To Do bar, Outlook will show months in calendar bar.

Answer (score 0):

Menu View -> Current View -> Day/Week/Month

[image]